# Read on raw socket and udp socket

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a virtual interface bound to some vlan. I have 2 sockets, 1 is a raw socket, and another is a UDP socket bound to port 8900. Both sockets are attached to the same virtual interface. When I send a UDP datagram to port 8900 to that interface, I can see the UDP socked is receiving the packet. Question is, is the raw socket also notified for this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kernel creates multiple copies of the Ethernet frame. If your virtual interface gets a Ethernet frame all sockets get a copy of the frame.